# Experiencing issues drawing layered graphics

Tags: java, recursion, draw

I have an open ended school project and I am attempting something somewhat intricate but I am having issues when it come to drawing the graphic layers properly.

I am trying to drawArc recursive spirals on top of fillOval recursive Concentric circles. I have moved the recursive call for fillOval both before and after the recursive calls for the spirals and it hasn't changed the end effect where the spirals aren't even created. But if I use drawOval the concentric circles appear overlapping with the spirals.

My Code is displayed below:
I am currently using BlueJ as that is the designated program for my class.

`     import java.awt.*;
      import javax.swing.*;

```
public class DrawPicture extends JApplet
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private final int SIZE = 600;
private final int DIST = 20;
private final int DELTA = 1;
public int i = 1;

public void recCirc(int xy, Graphics page, int clr)
{
    if(xy <= SIZE/2)
    {
       if(clr%2 == 0)
            page.setColor(Color.magenta);
       else
            page.setColor(Color.green);
    }
    page.drawOval(xy, xy, SIZE-2*xy, SIZE-2*xy);
    recCirc(xy + DIST, page, clr+1);
}

public void drawRec(int xy, int angle, Graphics page)
{

    if(angle < 360*2)
    {
        page.drawArc(xy, xy, SIZE-2*xy, SIZE-2*xy, angle, DELTA);
        drawRec(xy+DELTA, angle + DELTA, page);
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics page)
{

    page.setColor(Color.blue);
    drawRec(0, 0, page);
    page.setColor(Color.red);
    drawRec(0, 45, page);
    page.setColor(Color.blue);
    drawRec(0, 90, page);
    page.setColor(Color.red);
    drawRec(0, 135, page);
    page.setColor(Color.blue);
    drawRec(0, 180, page);
    page.setColor(Color.red);
    drawRec(0, 225, page);
    page.setColor(Color.blue);
    drawRec(0, 270, page);
    page.setColor(Color.red);
    drawRec(0, 315, page);
    recCirc(0, page, 0);
}
```

}`

As a secondary but not necessary answer, if someone would know how to use fillArc and I guess with a decreasing radius make it so the arc's drew correctly and made a proper filled spiral design I'd be intrested in the answer,.. I can only imagine it must use some form of decreasing radius to do it,.. darned if I can puzzle it out.

Thank you in advance for any insight given.

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to achieve, but your recursive call doesn't seem to have exits point. Stack will eventually overflow.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is to draw filled concentric circles (will look like a bullseye) and have the spirals overlap the bullseye. I have drawOval in the code now, so I realize that I won't get the bullseye I'm looking for, I had switched it too drawOval to see if the circles and spirals were even displaying together and they do when both are draw, when fillOcal is used though the bullseye becomes the top layer graphic regardless of where I put the call for it. I'm trying to figure out why that's happening and make it so the bullseye doesn't cover the spirals.

Comment: you have many issues; does the recursive draw end ever?? and how is the angle to get more than 360?